# Disney's "Very Merry Christmas Party"—mid-November crowds?

Tags: orlando, disney

I'm taking my son on a surprise, 1-night trip to Orlando.  He's been to Walt Disney World once and LOVED it.  I noticed that during this time they'll have the Very Merry Christmas Party going on at the Magic Kingdom, and thought it might be a good thing for us to go to.  We're arriving November 15th, a Thursday, and I was planning on going to the MK that night.  Does anyone know what sort of crowd levels we could expect?  I'm hoping that since it's early in the holiday season (November) and a weeknight (Thursday) the crowds won't be too terrible.  But, I've also read stories on the web about huge crowd levels.

Does anyone have any first-hand experience they can share?  Since we're only going down for 1 night I want to make sure we can make the most of our time.

Comment: well, I have no information actually, but after checking this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSrmW8VB6Io) which was taken in November 12, 2010 (similar to your situation) it shows that the crowd is not that much... hope this will help..

Answer (score 3):

November is very much off-season for Disney - Christmas Crowds begin in mid-December and then drop off again shortly after New Years.  The one variable this year is that the FantasyLand extension was scheduled for October, but crowds will still be far less than the Christmas Invasion that starts the second week of December.

As someone who worked at "Mouse-chwitz" for a year (developing websites in the "Hot Set" next to Toy Story Mania), I can heartily tell you that September - November, and January - March are the times to visit.  The crowds are minimal, the temperature is great, and the cast that sticks around is experienced. If you are doing the water parks, November is better, because they close for cleaning in February and March (one at a time, for several weeks.)

If you want exact times, there are several free Disney World apps that show actual wait times at attractions. Disney itself holds on to these same data very tightly, so you'll need to go with the third party apps to see it.